# Pandas: Selecting Column based on row content

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose you have the following dataframe:

```
        Col1     Col2    Col3    Col4   Col5
Index
Row1    Code1   Code2   Code3  Code4  Code5
Row2    1       0       1       1       0
Row3    10      0       10      0       10
Row4    7070    56746   87647   969     687876
Row5    98798   79657   6876    977     6678
```

Is there a way to select columns based on criteria for the rows (index)?

So for instance,

```
for all columns with Row2==1:
    do something with all the rows in those columns
```

and similarly

```
for all columns with Row3==0:
    do something with all the rows in those columns
```

etc.

I was thinking something like

```
for "Row3" in df.index:
    if "Row3" == 0:
        # Do certain calculation
```

Comment: Your DataFrame organization is a bit inverted. DataFrames are organized by columns of a **single** datatype. Given that row1 is a string and the rest are numeric your DataFrame is better organized as the transpose of what you have. Your current organization requires everything to be upcast to object and also makes your slicing a bit more awkward and complicated than it needs to be. In particular, the `object` upcasting will have serious consequences for future manipulations.

Comment: I agree with @ALollz entirely. It’s better to invest the time to fix this design issue than to just go for a quick “solution”.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up just transposing the data each time I needed to reference in this way. Saved me the head-ache.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m2 = df.loc['Row2'].eq(1)
#m2 = df.loc['Row2'].eq('1') #if string type

cols_Row2 = df.columns[m2]
#Index(['Col1', 'Col3', 'Col4'], dtype='object')

#for col in cols_Rows2:
    #.....
```

---

**Indexing the dataframe**

```
df.loc[:,m2] 
#         Col1    Col3    Col4
#Index                        
#Row1    Code1   Code3   Code4 
#Row2        1       1       1
#Row3       10      10       0
#Row4     7070   87647     969
#Row5    98798    6876     977
```

Comment: appreciate the answer! But ended up just transposing the data back